# Why is encapsulation problematic for ORM?

Tags: oop, orm

I'm trying to understand the problem with ORM, and the [wikipedia article on ORM mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) starts with:

> Object-oriented programs are designed with techniques that
> result in encapsulated objects whose representation is hidden.
>
> Mapping
> such private object representation to database tables makes such
> databases fragile according to OOP (object-oriented programming)
> philosophy, since
> there are significantly fewer constraints for design
> of encapsulated private representation of objects compared to a
> database's use of public data, which must be amenable to upgrade,
> inspection and queries.

Could anybody expand on this fragility? What are these constraints?

The operations seem to me to be about reading rows (inspections and queries) to objects and writing objects (upgrades) to rows. What's the big deal?